# Auto suggestion in Google Maps is not same at web and API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I get the program with the clumsiness of data appearance on the google API,
because if we do a direct address search on maps.google.com then the suggestion data will appear more, on the contrary if using the display API suggestion less, well how to display the suggestion API can be in accordance with the results suggestion search on maps.google.com

for the demo here: http://dzkrrbb.com/demo/gojek/

120/5000
enter the place name in the address like my example "masjid al ihsan", then compare the result on maps.google.com

Comment: Google Maps and the Google Maps API are different things, different results should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using Geocoding API instead of Place Autocomplete.

If you type "masjid al ihsan" in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), you get the same results that Google Maps.